# Best path to migrate a preexisting Flex/Java/Hibernate/MySQL app onto a CD for portable distro?

Tags: mysql, apache-flex, actionscript-3, hibernate, portability

I have a typical Flex-based application that was written to use a Java/Hibernate/MySQL backend.  The client changed the requirements - now they want to distribute it on a CD where the user can just run the app without any installation or a network connection.

**What is the recommended migration path for this situation?**

To do this, I certainly need to eliminate the web server and the database server and adapt my application (with as few changes as possible, of course) to a stand-alone application that will fit on a CD/DVD.

I've managed to export the data to XML and read it into Flex, but I'm wondering if there's a way to recreate the Hibernate data structures in Flex so I could change as little code as possible.  Failing that, is there any way to keep the existing Java/Hibernate external to the Flex code but retrievable without installing Apache Tomcat or MySQL?  What other options exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the simplest way to make this work, you probably want to keep the service tier (i.e. Java/Hibernate/mySQL) since switching to AIR means you will have to rewrite that logic in flex again. I would suggest running Jetty directly on the client machine (assuming that they have Java) and using HSQLDB as the backing datastore (which supports just having a database in-memory). Serve the flash file from Jetty as well and point the client's browser at a local URL. Better yet, have a simple java app that includes an embedded browser so the jetty instance would be killed when the user closes the app.

Apart from configuring everything on the java-end, the amount of code to rewrite should be minimal.

See:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Answer (score 1):

I also would like use an AIR application.
Use the SQLite-Database. I use it also for some projects and it works fine. There are import-tools from mysql to sqlite (meastro) and if my lookup to google was correct, there is a dialect for sqlite in hibernate.

so i think, you can kept your backend.

=======

ups, sorry, now i read, that you can't install the air engine. So my idea is a bad.

========

But what i can't understand is: Its allowed to install the flashplayer, to display your content, but its not allowed to install the air player. Where is the deiiferent. And there are many computers in the world without the flashplayer. You cannot assume, that the fp isinstalled in first case. What happens then?

======

Another idea can be an exe file.

I never tried it, but check this out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275896/execute-an-external-exe-from-flex-air-or-java-web-application)

Comment: It's not for any computer in the world, it's for a specific client.  So I can assume that the flash player is installed.

Comment: The Air2Exe solution seems pretty good, but I still don't see any reason Flash can't do whatever Air can do.  I don't see that this solves my problem.  SQLite however might be the answer.

Comment: okay, what i understand is, that you need a solution to distribute your webcontent on a cd. So we have two problems. First we need a plattform, which can display your content. A Browser is no option, because it is not distributable and you can't install AIR. So my Idea is, to convert AIR in EXE. So no player needs to install. The second is, we have to move your backend to local ressources. So AIR and SQLite can be a option.

Answer (score 0):

For a standalone application, you'll want to compile it as an AIR application instead of Flex. 
My suggestion:

- Create a new AIR Project
- Copy and paste most of your logic, shouldn't need many adjustments
- Now in AIR you'll have filesystem access to read in your XML/CSV data from SQL Exports

  ```
  protected function file_select(event:Event):void
  {   
      file = (event.target as File);
      file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, file_completeHandler);
      file.load();
  }

  protected function file_completeHandler(event:Event):void
  {
      var xmlList:XMLList = XML(event.result);
      //Now do your thing with the XML (You will most likely want to change the line above(
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you, but I've already got the SQL Export read into Flex--that's not the problem.  I want the XML object in Flex to behave like the Hibernate objects in Java.  And I can't use AIR for other reasons, but that isn't hindering anything.

Comment: Why can't you use AIR?  It would be nicer than if it was just loaded in the browser, no?

Comment: Can't install any apps on the user's computer, including the AIR engine.

Comment: @ HuckIt - java machine, air runtime, flash player - your app anyway needs at least one of those, so in some cases the user will have to install something. it's rather sad but http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/ says that 99% PCs have flashplayer installed and 80% - JRE, so imho usage of java shouldn't cause much more trouble than usage of flash

Comment: those 19% include an awful lot of people.